# PasswordHasher updating user information

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, password-protection, password-hash

The `PasswordHasher` takes in a generic `TUser` and then takes the user's object for hashing and verifying, something like this:

```
var result = hash.VerifyHashedPassword(user, HashedPassword, Password);

string HashedPassword = hash.HashPassword(user, Password);
```

So I am assuming the user data is used to hash the password and then to verify. But doesn't this mean I need to rehash the password? If so, wouldn't that mean each time the user changes any of his account info he also needs to re-enter his password or is there a way around it where I can rehash it without asking the user for his password?

Comment: Rather bizarrely, the user parameter appears not to be used https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Core/PasswordHasher.cs#L172 . Anyway, you will only need to -and be able to- re-hash the password when the user changes it.

Comment: Thinking about it, the parameter may be there to allow for extension.

Comment: this is interesting. it also maybe the other way around. They stopped using the parameter but had to leave it for backward compatibility

Comment: Yes, that is plausible.